# How to create a Domain Name for a Django App in a LAN

Tags: django, linux, nginx

I recently built a Django app that I am running on a Linux machine with Gunicorn and NGINX. The app is being run inside my company's network which is predominantly a windows environment. Currently, I am able to access the web app via the server's IP address. I know if it was a windows machine I could use the DNS to have it called by a DN. How accomplish this given that it's a Linux machine? For example, I would like to have the company users call the web app from a browser using http://analytics instead of its IP address. Would make the app much more user-friendly instead of always typing in the IP and just for best practice it's probably not secure to be showing the end user the IP anyways.

Comment: Yah - just add it to DNS.

Comment: Set up a DNS server and domain, have the router point to it,. (Or whatever routes your network segment, does not have to be specifically the router.)

Comment: if you can access the LAN application you can set the DNS name with IP following this tutorial https://www.draytek.com/support/knowledge-base/5151

Comment: @tink I think it is on our DNS but when I call it from the browser (http://example-server) all I get is an APACHE2  Default Page, I am relatively new with all this stuff so I'm not sure how to get it to go to my django-nginx-guinicorn site (which is still callable only from IP)

Comment: **IF** it is in DNS (and *I think it is* doesn't instill me with confidence) you have a much bigger problem. If you have both nginx and apache2 running on the same machine you'd wonder who gets the port, why it works via IP but not the name. To be honest, I'm now starting to think that this question doesn't belong on SO at all but rather to [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) since it's a DNS/Networking/Server-setup issue.

Comment: Sorry let me recorrect, I know apache isn't running because i stopped it in the terminal, the index page for apache shows when calling the DN from the browser. The machine is also on our Windows DNS I just don't know how to get it to serve the django app instead of the appache index page, I'll post over on Webmasters thx